# What means: MediaPlayer - This is not a sprint project

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

While working with the `MediaPlayer` I recognized this log message and wondered about its meaning.
Does anyone have an idea? The player works fine but this message seems strange.

```
02-21 18:25:44.157: I/MediaPlayer(21538): This is not a sprint project
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that this print is coming from a phone caller application or a `Youtube` kind of application. I think this print has been put to identify that the network provider is not Sprint. There is a very similar log for HTC One as in this [post](https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/67650-cant-play-this-video-on-3g-htc-one/). It looks like a customized version of the `MediaPlayer` to print the statistics of the connection setup.

Comment: In the mean time, I saw similar log messages that support this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you forgot to include permissions for internet in your manifest xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

I am also trying to create a MediaPlayer app. And because I was missing the internet permission I got exactly the same message / error.

Comment: Internet Permission is already included. That is not the problem.

Comment: Yes ... you are right ... I still have the same message ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is an internal error that got out.

[Sprint Software Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprint_%28software_development%29)